# Passing a form POST parameter between two javascript functions

Tags: javascript

This is my html code:

```
<form name="frmMain" action ="<?php echo(htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); ?>"
 method="post" onsubmit="return validateform(this);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ...
 ...
  ...
<button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default" 
    style="position: relative; float:right; margin-right: 50px;">Submit Evaluation 
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
</form>
```

When the submit evaluation button is clicked, this function in javascript triggers:

```
function validateform(frm)
{
    var html=""; // to store the html content

    // Build the content of the create vendor popup form
    html+="<div class='col-md-12 divPreview' id='divPreview'>\n\
<div class='col-md-12 divBackground' id='divBackground'>\n\
<button type='submit' name='btnSubmit' class='btn btn-default' onclick='return SubmitForm(frm);'>Submit</button>\n\
</div></div>";

    $("#divPreview").html(html); // display processing popup form
    return(false);
}
```

It is really a preview div with a button to submit to the following method:

```
function SubmitForm(frm)
{
    .. do some processing here
    frm.submit(); // submit the form
    return(false); // to prevent the calling form from executing
}
```

How to pass the frm form parameter from validateform() to submitform()?

I did this and now it's working:

```
function validateform(frm)
{
    var html=""; // to store the html content

    // Build the content of the create vendor popup form
    html+="<div class='col-md-12 divPreview' id='divPreview'>\n\
<div class='col-md-12 divBackground' id='divBackground'>\n\
<button type='submit' name='btnSubmit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></div></div>";

    $("#divPreview").html(html); // display processing popup form
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){ SubmitForm(frm); });
    return(false);
}
```

Comment: I think you just have to update `onclick='return SubmitForm(frm)` to `onclick='return SubmitForm(this)` you are passing the form to the function, it doesn't have to be named `frm`

Comment: Write a third function that calls the other two inside it?